# Why is this Prolog program returning true AND false?

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

i'm new to Prolog, and try to understand why this very simple program is return 2 solutions : true AND false. For me, this should return only true, why return false too ?

```
predicate1(_,[]).
predicate1(X,[_|T]) :- predicate1(X,T).

?- predicate1(abc,[]).
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This gets asked *a lot*. Firstly realize that the predicate is not *returning* true or false. It is succeeding or failing. When it succeeds and finds a solution, it shows `true`. If it goes back to a choice point to find an other solution and doesn't find one, it then fails (to find another solution)\ and says `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal unifies with the first clause (a fact) for the predicate:

```
?- predicate1(abc,[]) = predicate1(_,[]).
true.
```

Thus the query returns `true` as its first result. But a choice-point is created as there's a second clause (a rule) for the predicate. As the unification of the goal and the head of the rule fails, you get `false` when asking for a second solution:

```
?- predicate1(abc,[]) = predicate1(X,[_|T]).
false.
```